# Binary search - Can someone clear up this interview algorithm?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I recently had an interview where the interviewer gave me the following scenario and asked me what data structure I'd use to implement it:

You have 100 marbles and each marble is either red, blue, or green. The marbles are thrown into a bag and you need to have some mechanism of retrieving a random-colored marble (with replacement).

Okay, easy enough. After asking some questions about the constraints, I told him I would use a simple array where each bucket represents one marble. A random number function can be used to index the array, thus producing a random colored marble.

That solution was fine, but then he asked "what if you have many different colors, each with <= 1,000,000,000 marbles?" Initially I suggested to use a hash table where each key represents a color and each value represents the number of marbles in that color. The interviewer told me that was a good fix for the space constraint, but now the probability of producing one of the n colors was 1/n, rather than the actual probability given by the marble totals. I needed some way to keep the probabilities the same without storing them all in memory. I ended up not thinking of anything, and the solution he gave me was this:

Find the total of each color (this would be O(n), which is fine for a setup) and set up an array where each bucket represents the cumulative total of each of the colors. For example, if your marble totals were R: 3, B: 5, G: 1,000,000,000, then the array would look like [3] [8] [1,000,000,008]. Then he said you can now use a binary search with a random index to obtain a marble of a random color while still maintaining the correct probabilities. Can anyone explain to me why this is the case? Would this just be a modified binary search that returns the first value that is higher than your random index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that you look at the index where your binary search ends instead of the value at that position. I did not know of this algorithm yet. Thanks for your description. I implemented it in python for you :)

```
import random
import bisect

# 10 red, 20 blue, 70 green
counts = [10, 20, 70]
sums   = [10, 30, 100]

# count how often some color occurs to verify later that the algorithm works correctly
bins = [0, 0, 0]
# randomly select 10000 colors
for _ in range(100000):
    random_index = random.randint(0, sums[-1]) # sums[-1] is the last value in array (100)
    # do binary search in sums array
    result = bisect.bisect_left(sums, random_index)
    bins[result] += 1

print(bins) # example output: [10875, 19732, 69393]
```

Comment: Nice! I sort of understood the application but not so much the implementation. This cleared things up, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a random index between 1 and N for choosing a marble color, then the probability of getting a particular color is k / N, where k is the number of numbers that are assigned to that color. Your interviewer was simply putting the colors in order so that each color had the correct number k assigned indices to it (where k was the number of original marbles of that color), and then noting that given a random index between 1 and N, you could binary search to find which color's range that random index lied in. Assuming the random index between 1 and N is uniformly random, this will give you the correct probability k / N of getting a color when there are k marbles with that color.

Comment: Okay, so to clarify, when you perform the binary search with index i, you aren't explicitly looking for i, correct?

Comment: Not per se, no. One way to go is to make an array of size 2M where M is the number of marble colors where the 2 integers for each color are the start and end numbers between 1 and N for that color. Then binary search to find out which TWO indices i is between (or which index i is equal to). It's also possible to do it with an array of size M but a bit harder to explain.